# "No database selected" error with mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class ll{
          function ll(){
            include "sql.php";
          }

         function getUser($ID) {
            $sql="select * FROM users where ID=$ID";
            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
            $obj = mysql_fetch_object($res);
            return $obj;
    }

        function setOfflineALL() {
            $sql="update users set online=0";
            mysql_query($sql);
        }

 }
        $services = new ll();
        $services->setOfflineALL(); // THIS WORKS !
        $services->getUser(1); // THIS GIVES error: No database selected 


        ?>
```

and sql.php is:

```
<?php   $hostname_con1 = "localhost";
        $database_con1 = "db1";
        $username_con1 = "root";
        $password_con1 = "mypass";
        $con1 = mysql_connect($hostname_con1, $username_con1, $password_con1) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
        mysql_select_db($database_con1);
        mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con1);

?>
```

- sql.php is correct (no error)
- setOfflineALL works fine (no error)
- getUser raises "no database selected error !", however I do select one with mysql_select_db

I do use php5.4

Any clue ?

I also tried:

```
function getUser($ID) {
            $hostname_con1 = "localhost";
            $database_con1 = "db1";
            $username_con1 = "root";
            $password_con1 = "mypass";
            $con1 = mysql_connect($hostname_con1, $username_con1, $password_con1) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
            mysql_select_db($database_con1);
            mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con1);

                $sql="select * FROM users where ID=$ID";
                $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                $obj = mysql_fetch_object($res);
                return $obj;
        }
```

And still have error:
**No database selected**

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: ok.. I know that . Howver error_reporting(E_ALL); does not show me any warning or errors !

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
mysql_select_db($database_con1, $con1);
```

And you should give your database variable to your query too:

```
mysql_query("query", $con1);
```

And I strongly advise you not to use mysql but use PDO or mysqli
[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
[Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: I tried this: STILL SAME problem !!!

Comment: providing the `$con1` like this will not work due to the variable scopes. You'd have to store the variable in your class to be able to use it in all functions.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Please don't state the obvious, I just wrote it out as example and not how the OP should use it in his code.

Comment: The way the class in the OP is written makes it clear that it is not obvious.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Please, you see that OP is using multiple functions in a class so YES it is obvious that he should set a private variable inside his class.

Comment: Yes absolutely @Stijn is correct. You can also take a new variable name for  database name.